# Продлема с БД RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Когда обновляю страницу в бд добавляется во все колонки значение NULL

```
<?php
require "db.php";
?>

<form action="signup.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
<input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Возраст">
<input type="number" name="salary" placeholder="Зарплата">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
<?php

$data=$_GET;
if(isset($data['button'])){
  $errors=array();
  if(trim($data['name'])==""){
    echo "Необходимо вписать имя";
  }
  if(trim($data['age'])==""){
    echo "Поля заполнены неверно";
  }
  if(trim($data['salary'])==""){
    echo "Поля заполнены неверно";
  }
if(R::count('users',"name = ?",array($data['name']))
>0){
  echo "Такая персона существует";
}
}
$book = R::dispense( 'people');
$book->name = $data['name'];
$book->age = $data['age'];
$book->salary = $data['salary'];
R::store( $book );

 ?>
```

Comment: Так и будет, у вас запись в базу выполняется в любом случае, переместите его в блок if или else по логике

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы только начали изучать php вот рабочий пример для вас, но попробуйте его понять, у вас достаточно много ошибок, для начала данные вы передаете post запросом а проверяете get. Форма также должна быть а не input

```html
<?php
require "db.php";

$data = $_POST;
$errors = [];

if (isset($data['button'])) {
  if (trim($data['name']) == "") {
    $errors[] = "Необходимо вписать имя";
  }
  if (trim($data['age']) == "") {
    $errors[] = "Поле возраста заполнены неверно";
  }
  if (trim($data['salary']) == "") {
    $errors[] = "Поле зарплаты заполнены неверно";
  }
  if (
    R::count('users', "name = ?", array($data['name']))
    > 0
  ) {
    $errors[] = "Такая персона существует";
  }
}

if (!$errors) {
  $book = R::dispense('people');
  $book->name = trim($data['name']);
  $book->age = trim($data['age']);
  $book->salary = trim($data['salary']);
  R::store($book);
} else {
  echo '<div>';
  foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . '<br>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}

?>

  <hr>

  <form action="signup.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" value="<?= $data['name'] ?>">
    <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Возраст" value="<?= $data['age'] ?>">
    <input type="number" name="salary" placeholder="Зарплата" value="<?= $data['salary'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Отправить">
  </form>
```